# How do I change the colours of specific labels in ng2-charts?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I made a doughnut chart using ng2-charts in Angular 8. I have 3 labels in my doughnut chart, 'Passed', 'Failed' and 'Open'. I want to set 'Green', 'Red' and 'Blue' for those labels respectively. How do I do this?
My compliance.component.html file

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div style="display: block">
            <canvas baseChart 
            [data]="doughnutChartData" 
            [labels]="doughnutChartLabels" 
            [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
            [options]="doughnutChartOptions"
            [colors]="doughnutChartColor">
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My compliance.component.ts file

```
export class ComplianceComponent implements OnInit {

  public doughnutChartLabels: Label[] = ['Passed', 'Open', 'Fail'];
  public doughnutChartData: MultiDataSet = [
    [30, 20, 50]
  ];

  public doughnutChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut';
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public doughnutChartColor: Array<any> = [
    { // first color
      'Passed'-color:green;
      'Failed'-color:red;
      'Open'-color:blue;
    }];

    public doughnutChartOptions={
      responsive: true
    };
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`colors` must be defined as an `array` of `interface` [`Color`](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/blob/development/projects/ng2-charts/src/lib/color.ts) according to the following code snippet:

```
import { Color } from 'ng2-charts';
...
public doughnutChartColor: Color[] = [
    { backgroundColor: 'green' },
    { backgroundColor: 'red' },
    { backgroundColor: 'blue' }
];
```